# Can you have CSS box shadow (inset) show on video element

Tags: html, css

I added a box shadow to a `<div>` and added a `<video>` element to the div.
The box shadow shows up on the div, however it doesn't affect the video element.

Is this the expected behaviour, and is there a way to get the box shadow to affect the video as well?

**Code snippet:**

```css
.video-player {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 103px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 103px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 103px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

```html
<div class="video-player">
    <video width="100%">
        <source src="http://example.com/1wIsuB2" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
    <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

This clearly isn't a big issue, but I found it rather interesting.

**EDIT:** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dbt6g5ra/)

**EDIT 2:** This is for inset shadows

**EDIT 3:** It is possible to show an inset shadow on the video element. It requires an additional ement. If you want to achieve this see the answer  @cport1 gave

Comment: Can you give a JSFiddle link?

Comment: If the video is Flash, you may need to change the transparency on the video itself. see: http://www.aleosoft.com/flashtutorial_transparent.html

Comment: The video is an mp4. I've added a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/dbt6g5ra/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The box-shadow is part of the parent element, so it renders below the video. One alternative is to have a div which places a shadow over the video like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/dbt6g5ra/1/

```
<div class="video-player">
    <video class="vid" width="100%">
        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <div class="shadow"></div>
</div>


.video-player {
//styles
    
}
.shadow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 36px 36px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. So the video renders above the `div`, but other elements inside the div are affected by the box shadow.

Comment: Are there other elements like `<video>` that won't be affected by the box shadow? divs, spans etc. seem to work just fine. Does the video element belong to a specific set of tags?

Comment: an <img> tag will act the same as <video>

Comment: As I mention below, box-shadow works just fine on the video element, no extra markup needed. See: http://html5multimedia.com/code/ch6/css-rounded-corners-and-shadow.html

Comment: It doesn't work according to the fiddle and the code I posted above. The shadow is inset

Comment: Why was this voted down? The JS Fiddle I provided in the question demonstrates that the box shadow is not showing up on the video element, however trying this answer it does. 

If this is browser specific, I am using Chrome 38.0 on OSX

Comment: @ianDevlin that's not an inset box-shadow.

Comment: I completely missed that he wanted an inset shadow, it was only mentioned in the code which I somehow didn't see.

Answer (score -1):

The `video` element extends to height of the video and stops. It is applying the shadow but you can't see it. If you add the shadow and a bottom padding (e.g. of 30px) to the `video` element the shadow will appear.

**EDIT:**
I'd like to point out that I completely missed that the OP wanted an inset shadow, the OP has since edited the title to make this clearer.

Comment: I tried adding padding and the shadow to the video but the video is still unaffected by the shadow. http://jsfiddle.net/gzcj7f7q/1/

Comment: I can see the shadow in your jsfiddle in Firefox? What browser are you using?

Comment: Here is an example of box-shadow on an example from my book, which works just fine: http://html5multimedia.com/code/ch6/css-rounded-corners-and-shadow.html

Comment: He's asking for inset box-shadow to go over the video.

Comment: I completely missed that he wanted an inset shadow, it was only mentioned in the code which I somehow didn't see.

Answer (score -3):

Just do it

```
.video-player {
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px #888;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't quite seem to do much

Comment: I did in my computer and worked well. But I changed the width to 90% .Hugs

Comment: @Jones was requesting for inset box-shadow.